# Paquetes en Java

Tags: java, windows10, packages

Buen día a todos!

Hice un proyecto x pero todos mis archivos estaban desordenados, por lo que decidí agruparlos por carpetas.

carpetaa

---ClaseA.java

---ClaseB.java

carpetab

---Clase1.java

Main.java

El problema surge cuando intento compilar, ya que en el main me aparece que no es encuentran las clases que hice

Creí que esto se solucionaba poniendo en las clases

```
package src.carpetaa.ClaseA;
```

Y en las otras lo mismo

```
package src.carpetaa.ClaseB;
```

Y

```
package src.carpetab.Clase1;
```

Asi en todas las clases, Y en el main poner

```
import src.carpetaa.*;
import src.carpetab.*;
```

Pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error aunque le ponga los paquetes

Cabe aclarar que no creé las carpetas en el editor de código, sino en el mismo sistema de Archivos de windows

¿A que se debe esto? Gracias!

Comment: package src.carpetaa.ClaseA;   Esto es incorrecto, te sugiero que pongas la estrcutura de tus pakages en la descripcion

Comment: dale un rebuild pueda que eso corrija el error pues existe la posibilidad de que hagan referencia a las rutas antiguas